# How to install a client certificate for a service account

Tags: windows, client-certificate

I'm building an application that needs to access a third-party webservice, for which I have a client certificate. This works if I run the application from my own account, but eventually, the application will need to run as a service.

I have two questions:

- I think that a client certificate should be installed in a 'Personal' store. Is that correct? (I tried to install the cert in the Local Computer's Trusted Root Certification section too, but then it seems to be ignored)
- How can I install a client certificate in the personal store of a service account? Or is it possible to install a client certificate for all users?

If it matters: This is a .NET Core application running on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done through the usual GUI "Certificates" management console, but instead of using the predefined `certmgr.msc` or `certlm.msc`, you will need to use a custom configuration:

1. Run `mmc` (Microsoft Management Console).
2. Open *File → Add or Remove Snap-In*.
3. Select "Certificates" and click "Add >".
4. You will be asked which account's certificates the snap-in will manage.
5. Click OK.

(You can add as many snap-ins as you want, and save the console as a `*.msc` file for later use.)

Comment: It is important to note that mmc.exe should be run 'as administrator'. If you don't, it will not give you the option to select an account.